# Equation with sectioning numbering problem

Tags: sectioning, equations, numbering

I need special numbering for equations in my work, so I made it similar to figures numbering which egreg wrote [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132954/caption-and-sections-subsections-and-subsubsections)

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%numeriranje jednadžbe
\renewcommand{\theequation}{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}=0
    \thesection.\arabic{figure}%
  \else
    \ifnum\value{subsubsection}=0
      \thesubsection.\arabic{figure}%
    \else
      \thesubsubsection.\arabic{figure}%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  R' &= R/255 \\
  G' &= G/255 \\
  B' &= B/255
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  C_{max} &= max(R', G', B') \\
  C_{min} &= min(R', G', B') \\
  \Delta &= C_{max} - C_{min}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

It gives me this type of numbering, which is good, but the number of equation is wrong:
[image: wrong numbering on my MWE]

If I use it in my document it looks like this:
[image: wrong numbering in document]

The `2.1.2.` part is fine, that's the number of my subsubsection, but the rest is wrong. It should be `2.1.2.1` and `2.1.2.2`
Could you tell me what have I done wrong here?

Comment: you want `{equation}` not `{figure}` in each case, you are incrementing the equation counter then printing the figure one, change to print the equation counter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two separate issues with the code in your MWE:

- You need to affix `\arabic{equation}`, not `\arabic{figure}`, to the various redefinitions of `\theequation`. This has already been pointed out by David Carlisle. (This is why the first couple of equation numbers terminate in `.0`. My guess is that your document has two `figure` environments prior to the second batch of equations you show; it's the most straightforward explanation of why the final digit of both equation numbers is stuck at `.2`.)
- You're missing the following statements (adapted from [@egreg's earlier answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133172/5001)):

  ```
  \usepackage{chngcntr}
  \counterwithin*{equation}{section}
  \counterwithin*{equation}{subsection}
  \counterwithin*{equation}{subsubsection}
  ```

If you don't include these commands, the final digit of the composite equation "number" will happily increase from 1 to 2 to 3 and so on regardless of the sectioning level the equations happen to be in.

An off-topic comment: Don't typeset "max" and "min" in plain math-italic mode. Use `\max` and `\min` where they occur as math operators, and write `C_{\textup{max}}` and `C_{\textup{min}}` for the subscript instances. If you have a lot of those instances, you define some macros in the preamble, say `\newcommand{\Cmax}{C_{\textup{max}}}`, and use `\Cmax` throughout the document.